# Is there a way to know if a div's contents are in a "clipped" state when overflow: hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to style a div differently when its contents are clipped due to overflow: hidden or overflow: scroll.

On some browser there is no indication that the contents can be scrolled through, and this is not great for usability.

As far as I know there is no pseudo class of :clipped or anything like that. But that would be very useful. Is there any way to do this without writing my own algorithm?

Javscript solutions also welcome...

Comment: compare element's actual/displayed height v.s. the content's height? it should show that your div is (say) 50px while the content is 900px

Comment: This sounds promising, but would require an extra markup tag. For example currently the contents are only inside the div that has overflow:scroll applied. I'll give it a shot...

Comment: should work for overflow:none as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Question:*** Can you indicate the type of content your  is holding (i.e., text or image or vector, etc.)

Comment: The reason of my asking, is the fact that it's not clear your expected behavior.

Comment: You may want to have an elipsis like ***<div style="text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden">***
Or you may want to clip it like ***<div style="text-overflow:clip; overflow:hidden">***

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
if ($("#div1").height() > $("#div1").outerHeight()) {
    //apply class1
} else {
    //apply class2
}
```

If you have an operation that changes the content of the element, this `if` could be used to apply a different class. `height()` gets the content height, whereas `outerHeight()` get the size of the outside of the `div`.